# Add custom button in sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Is it possible to add custom button like `btn_add` in sonata admin form? Also please can you tell me what is and how to use `btn_catalogue`?

```
->add('purchaseItems', 
    CollectionType::class, [
        'mybutton'     => "Update status",
        'by_reference' => false,
        'attr'         => ['required' => true]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it is totally possible, you just have to create a new custom action, following these steps:

> - extend the SonataAdmin:CRUD Controller and tell our admin class to    use it
> - create the custom action in our Controller
> - create a template    to show the action in the list view
> - add the route and the new action    in the Admin class

Everything is explained in documentation here:

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html